# ansible template module permission error

Tags: permissions, ansible

Snippet of my yaml code:

```
  - name: 11|Copy sw-installer.jinja2 response file for unattended installation

     template:
       src: "{{ CNTRL_SERVER_RSP_FILE_DIR_LOCATION_FOR_INSTALL }}/sw-installer.jinja2"
       dest: "/opt/something/{{ ENV_CHOSEN }}/tempLocation/sw-installer.conf"
       owner: joker
       group: circus
       mode: 2777
       backup: yes

     when:
       - ansible_facts['os_family'] == "CentOS" or ansible_facts['os_family'] == "RedHat"
       - ansible_distribution_version | int >= 6
       - http_dir_path.stat.exists == true
       - http_dir_path.stat.isdir == true
       - ChangeDirPermission is defined
       - ChangeDirPermission is succeeded

     register: CopyRspFileResult

   - debug:
       var: CopyRspFileResult
```

Runtime result:

```
TASK [11|Copy sw-installer.jinja2 response file for unattended installation] ********************************************
changed: [rm-host.company.com]

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************
ok: [rm-host.company.com] => {
    "CopyRspFileResult": {
        "changed": true,
        "checksum": "b0f86be744b2b0c767b4861e7a36800708c47ff9",
        "dest": "/opt/something/unitc/tempLocation/sw-installer.conf",
        "diff": [],
        "failed": false,
        "gid": 4912,
        "group": "circus",
        "md5sum": null,
        "mode": "05331",
        "owner": "joker",
        "secontext": "system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0",
        "size": 8534,
        "src": "/u/joker/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1561211521.59-240308852971878/source",
        "state": "file",
        "uid": 1124558737
    }
}
```

Running 2nd time:

```
TASK [11|Copy sw-installer.jinja2 response file for unattended installation] ********************************************
fatal: [rm-host.company.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "checksum": "b0f86be744b2b0c767b4861e7a36800708c47ff9", "msg": "Could not make backup of /opt/something/unitc/tempLocation/sw-installer.conf to /opt/something/unitc/tempLocation/sw-installer.conf.51030.2019-06-22@10:02:12~: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/something/unitc/tempLocation/sw-installer.conf'"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/u/sdbmiu/scripts/Ansible/playbooks/webagent/plays/WebAgent_Install.retry

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************
rm-host.company.com     : ok=7    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Points to note:

```
/opt/something/unitc/tempLocation has permission of 2775

Exact same error appears even if I use /tmp as remote location

I'm running as user joker on remote node. So not running as root or sudo. I don't have permission to do that.
```

ansible version

```
ansible 2.7.10
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/company/sdbmiu/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Mar 26 2019, 22:13:06) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]
```

Questions:

```
1. Why does it fails to set appropriate permission when mode: 2777 is specified? But on remote node, permission appear as (5331/--ws-wx--t)

2. Why should backup fail?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from your debug output, when you set mode to `2777`, it is interpreted as a decimal number, so the (octal) mode applied is `05331`.  You need to change

```
mode: 2777
```

to

```
mode: 02777
```

or

```
mode: '2777'
```

for ansible to recognize it as octal.

From [ansible template module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html): "You must either add a leading zero so that Ansible's YAML parser knows it is an octal number (like `0644` or `01777`) or quote it (like `'644'` or `'1777'`) so Ansible receives a string and can do its own conversion from string into number."

Comment: Thank you user4556274. It works. Also, backup problem is resolved with this.

For benefits of others, we could also use "mode: preserve" so that source permissions are same at target. Backup is only taken if source file is different than target.